# Socket.IO + Nginx connection limit

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, socket.io

I start servers using [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) and use Nginx as a load balance.
Now I try to load test servers.

I loop create connection and count how many connection are `connect` and log when `connect_error`.
When I connect to server through Nginx it error after ~500 connection everytime.

```
Opening SOCKET
   SOCKET connect 508
Opening SOCKET
   SOCKET connect 509
Opening SOCKET
connect_error
{ [Error: websocket error]
  description: 
     { [Error: socket hang up]
       code: 'ECONNRESET',
       target: 
          { domain: null,
            _events: [Object],
            _maxListeners: 10,
            _socket: null,
            _ultron: null,
            _closeReceived: false,
            bytesReceived: 0,
            readyState: 0,
            supports: [Object],
            extensions: {},
            _isServer: false,
            url: 'ws://MY_NGINX_SERVER/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
            protocolVersion: 13,
            binaryType: 'arraybuffer' } 
    } 
}
```

but if I directly connect to socket server it can have over 500 connections.

here is my Nginx config

```
server {
    listen   80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/load_test.log;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://SOCKETIO_SERVER/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I think it is something in Nginx config file but I can't find any help me.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Try increase maximum open file limit (ulimit).

Comment: I set ulimit -n to 500000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad, it have to config `worker_connections` in file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
events {
   worker_connections  60000;
}
```